# Rails 3.2 Emails being delayed for 11 mins before processed by Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

I have a Rails 3.2 app running on Heroku using Action Mailer and Sendgrid to send single transactional emails. Currently when the app sends an email, the request doesn't get received by Sendgrid to send out for 11 minutes. When viewing the received email in the inbox, the time will read the time it was received, but if you open up the email, it has the time (11 minutes prior) that the email request was originally generated. This is what I have in production.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port           => '587',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain         => 'heroku.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}


config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

I've never encountered this problem with Rails 4.0 apps, so is this a known issue with Rails 3.2?

Comment: I am seeing a similar 11 minute delay this week using SendGrid.  Emails are sent from .Net on Azure.

Comment: I work at SendGrid. The vetting process can be expedited. The Support team can help. Call, chat, or email them.
https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/203979566

Answer (score 27):

I've had this also.

After talking with their support, its an intentional delay, put into the system on new accounts.

Their system needs to 'learn' that you are not a spammer before it will remove the delay.

They said it should only be delaying for 'a short period of time', and there is no other way to remove it, other than just send legitimate emails, and wait.

Comment: Do you know how long after account creation the delay lasts?

Comment: Not sure exactly, sorry. I setup the account, found it was taking too long to deliver for me, so I left it, since they couldnt do anything for me. I then looked at it again 1 month later, and it was working fine then with no delay, so max 1 month I would say.

Comment: I chatted with SendGrid support and they sent me an email asking for more information so that they would remove the email delay. So there is a way around it.

Comment: Maybe they have changed their procedures now then. When I asked them, they said that was impossible, and you had to wait for the system to trust you, as the software didnt allow for that. Sounds like it could be better now then, if they will do it manually for you.

Comment: I'd image that this delay is present in all free accounts (to give paid accounts priority / quicker sending)

Comment: Holy shoot! This is the same thing that is happening to me (using ASP.NET MVC, though) !!!

Answer (score 1):

Some answers from the SendGrid docs: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/When_Emails_Are_Sent/seeing_a_delay_with_your_first_few_sends.html

Check shaunwhite above about getting ahold of support to expedite the process.